# I am trying to setup Grails 4 in IntelliJ Ultimate in Ubuntu 19.04, but I don't know how. These are things I have completed/tried:

Tags: ubuntu, java, intellij

I use SDK manager to install Grails using this command: `sdk install grails` 
And I launched IntelliJ, selected Grails for the new project. Selected **Java version 11.0.4** as Project SDK

Selected `/home/pranav/.sdkman/candidates/grails/4.0.0` as Grails SDK Home.
Now I know know what to do in Run/Debug Configuration section:
[image: problem 2]

Also, there are two messages in the Build: > Sync section:
[image: problem 1]

1.Run Build error [logs](https://pastebin.com/kche36Up)

2.Configure Build error [logs](https://pastebin.com/sm3CBWYy)